# How to plot a Histogram using python

Tags: python, histogram

I am new with Python and I would like to have a histogram of the values that I have in a text file. But I get a Histogram with only the first value of my text file (See figure)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thKHG.png)

My file text is as follows:

```
2.52549
2.52821
4.69718
4.81173
4.85834
4.87637
3.03348
3.21677
3.28373
3.11296
3.11947
3.14685
3.19684
3.19533
3.20035
3.36578
3.3899
3.40696
3.47841
3.54231
3.54343
5.20521
5.23496
5.23317
6.1397
6.18261
6.18782
6.1184
6.20701
6.25631
```

And my code as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
from pylab import show,hist

gaussian_numbers = np.random.randn(1000)
data_Distanz = np.genfromtxt('data_Distance.txt')
x = data_Distanz[0]
plt.hist(x)
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Distance in m")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.savefig('Histogram.png', bbox_inches='tight')
show()
```

I Would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to write `x = data_Distanz` and you do not need ploty.

Comment: The culprit would seem to be that line x = data_Distanz[0], you selected only the first element.

Comment: thanks you very much. It works